# What standard error should I use with correlated clusters in maximum likelihood estimation of multinomial logit

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bootstrap, standard-error, multinomial-logit, spatial-correlation

I have a dataset with 14 clusters. Each cluster is a time series of 80 periods with autocorrealtion, and I am doing maximum likelihood estimation of a structural multinomial logit model. I suspect there is across-cluster correlation.
Therefore, I am thinking two options:

1. Driscoll-kraay standard errors. While I have read about how to calculate it in OLS (from Stata Journal), I am struggle thinking what the se formula is in ML using information matrix. Any learning material is much appreciated!
2. Bootstrapping. I am not sure how I should do resampling when I have correlated clusters. I am wondering if the following resampling makes any sense:

   a. I first sample the 14 clusters with replacement.

   b. Then I divide the time series into $x$ blocks and sample (without replacement) $y$ continuous blocks for each selected clusters.

   I have some concerns about such resampling: my dataset consists of 14 subjects who repeatedly make group decisions. Theoretically group size and types of subjects in a groups can make a difference. So I am wondering if the first step will compromise the structural of original dataset.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to explicitly model the autocorrelation.  You might model cluster effects as random intercepts, but within-cluster effects need to be handled with something like a continuous-time AR(1) correlation structure.

Comment: But random intercepts cannot solve the cross-cluster correlation, can it? Maybe I understand it wrong..

Comment: I haven’t seen that addressed.  I would want to explicitly model the cross-cluster correlations using what is known about the study design.